# internal error with Xorg

Tags: 12.04

I've got a new system and am experiencing instability with it, so in need of narrowing down possible causes.  After updating the bios, I still experience lockups.  so I'm now running with just 1 harddrive installed and am wanting to see if that helps things or not.

Now my specific question today is an issue seen in powering up things this morning.  I ran into this error msg popped up "Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error" and it was assocated with /usr/bin/Xorg.

Consulting older questions asked about this, I examined the /var/log/Xorg.0.log file but did not see any error lines (EE).   Just wondering if people have suggestions on things to try, files to examine, or just what I might try to do to further debug this.  I think my system is working fine now, even with this happening, but one never likes to see errors like this.

thanks

Comment: Have you considered the previous log file at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it could be a graphics card driver issue. You could try using updated drivers by adding the xswat ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If that fails to work, you may have to provide some more specific hardware information to help solve the problem - i.e. what graphics card you have, what other components such as wifi/networking cards (can sometimes cause problems) - if you are at all unsure about what hardware you have, you could use

```
sudo lspci
```

and

```
sudo lshw -html > hw.htm
```

(the last command writes hardware info to a html document).

Comment: Of course, don't forget to reboot after upgrading drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the following solution from Viper1987 at [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1998352&p=12004195#post12004195) worked for me:

> Try renaming the `xorg.conf` to `xorg.conf.backup`. Reboot
>
> this file can be found in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Apparently this is an optional config file that can cause problems when the configuration is faulty for some reason.