# Unable to generate core dump after apport disable

Tags: c++, apport, segmentation-fault, gdb

Hi I'm currently programming c++ on Ubuntu and am unable to generate a core dump with a segmentation fault. I just get "Segementation fault" and not the (core dump) I have set ulimit -c unlimited.

I used to be able to generate core dumps but sometime ago they stopped coming. Maybe this is because I disabled apport because of this bug ["Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142016/sorry-ubuntu-12-04-has-experienced-an-internal-error).

So I was wondering what other steps are there to enabling core dumps after ulimit -c unlimited?

Answer (score 6):

Coredumps have to be enabled in the kernel in

```
/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

which can be set by

```
sysctl kernel.core_pattern=$coredump_name
```

e.g.

```
sysctl kernel.core_pattern=core
sysctl kernel.core_pattern=/var/crash/%E.%p.%t.%s
```

- `%E` gives the full pathname of the crashed program (with `/` replaced by `!`)
- `%p` gives the process ID of the crashed program
- `%t` gives the epoch timestamp
- `%s` gives the terminating signal number

Full details are in `man 5 core`.

The kernel's default is `core`, but it may be set to something else (or disabled) at boot time, using `/etc/sysctl.conf` or `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf` or similar. If you have the latter, then simply add a new file with a name that sorts after the others (perhaps starting with `z`); if not then edit the existing file. In that file put the parameter to the `sysctl` command above, e.g.

```
kernel.core_pattern=core
```

Comment: I think sysctl changes are temporary between boots: you need `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make them permanent.

Comment: You are quite correct. Edited to make this clear.